# Android relative layout click priority

Tags: android

I have  a problem with views in the relative layout. I have a condition in the screen when 2 views can come together at the same place. One view constant in one place. Other moving in the screen. The constant view has a click listener. Now because of the moving view  coming over constant view sometimes, the click not working for the constant view.

Is there a way to set priority for views under relative layout.

Comment: Maybe you could try to use `<requestFocus>` on the view you want to set the priority. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the command **android:clipChildren**. Set the value in XML to **true** on the view (or the view's parent) which interferes with the other view you want to touch.

Comment: Thanks mate... there was a different problem with the code, which is fixed. However this helped me with something else..